# Почему пропала меню админка WP?

Tags: wordpress

при попытке перехода в админку вордпресс выдает ошибку.По инфе из интернета дело в пробелах,но как я вижу,лишних пробелов нету,как в functions.php, так и в pluggable.php. В чем проблема?

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:63) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1265

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:63) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1268

**functions.php**
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/324030b1a9810ead3662174660b6a13a7aa772c5

**pluggable.php** со строчки 1248 по 1272
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d2c51be77150cf6fbb46242d1c28a22edeef80a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите закрывающую скобку`?>` в конце файла `functions.php`. Она не нужна, и может лишь нанести вред. Символы после неё трактуются как вывод на экран.

Также убедитесь, что этот файл имеет кодировку UTF-8 **без** BOM.

`pluggable.php` - это файл ядра, там всё правильно. В нём только генерируется сообщение об ошибке в вашем файле.

Comment: спасибо,помогло. Удивительно,что закрывающий тэг ?> послужил причиной,но почему? Это же закрывающий тэг

Comment: Я вам объяснил причину. Не закрывающий тег проблема, а пробелы или переводы строк после него. Убрали сам тег - и эти пробелы и переводы строк попали в код php и игнорируются. Оставили тег на месте - и эти символы трактуются как вывод на экран в режиме html.

Comment: Сделайте привычкой никогда не использовать закрывающий тег php в конце файла. Именно для избежания подобных ошибок использование закрывающего тега в конце запрещено стандартом кодирования WordPress.

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: спасибо вам!!!!!